# Compiling some CoffeeScript files on save

Tags: javascript, vim, coffeescript

I'm working with **CoffeeScript** in Node and the browser and only want to compile the files meant for the browser.

I have **vim** set up to compile the file if it has the extension `.js.coffee`, but that writes a file with the extension `.js.js`.  I can pass arguments into the compile command, but then I need **vim** to know the file name and then remove the extra `.js`.

Here is the relevant part of my vimrc file.

```
au BufWritePost *.js.coffee CoffeeMake!
```

Comment: Why not just edit `*.coffee` files, and have them compiled to `*.js` using `au BufWritePost *.coffee CoffeeMake!`?

Comment: I only want to compile some of the files.  I don't need to compile any of the files running in Node and don't want to have to manually compile files or remove unneeded files.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not very handy to compile on every save. I would recomend that you use [***Vim CoffeeScript extension***](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-coffee-script) as it will check your syntax on every save. Like this you will have immediate feedback does your code makes sense, testing will require additional step (keep reading) :-)

Another suggestion is to use .coffee for your extension instead .js.coffee. It just makes more sense and you will not have .js.js as result.

Back on compilation, when you write decent piece of code you can use [***cake***](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html) to compile your .coffee files in .js files so that you can refresh your browser and test. Cakefile is used as configuration which controls in which order your coffee scripts are compiled - quite handy with bigger projects.

It is quite easy to install and setup, invoking cake from vim while you are editing your project is then simply

```
:!cake build
```

and you can refresh your browser and see results.

As I'm also busy to learn the best way of structuring the files and use coffee script in combination with backbone and cake, I have created a [***small project on github***](https://github.com/pericazivkovic/coffeescript-backbone-sample) to keep it as a reference for myself, maybe it will help you too around cake and some basic things. All compiled files are in **www** folder so that you can open them in your browser and all source files (except for cake configuration) are in **src** folder. In this example, all .coffee files are compiled and combined in **one** output .js file which is then included in html. You can modify cake setup to create multiple .js files if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) and guard-coffeescript.
2. Cake file + filewatcher
3. 'coffee' command with -w argument http://coffeescript.org/#usage